# When and Why does G0 phase occur?

Tags: cell-biology, cardiology, neurology, cell-cycle

I've asked this question, specifically because i've seen this question.

[image]

As we see in this diagram , G0 phase occurs after M phase and at a specific point within G1 phase.

[image]

Is there a meaning to saying "end" in this case?

What is the checkpoint for causing a cell to enter G0 instead of continuing with the cell cycle, in case of heart cells and neurons? (what exactly is "checked"?).

Comment: Regarding when, I would answer at the end of Mitosis (check also this link:  https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70323/what-determines-the-reversibility-of-cell-of-g0-phase-in-cell-cycle?rq=1 ).
I wouldn't know what to answer to your second question, but maybe the link I posted above will help.